# How to convert a rectangle to triangle by using shortcuts in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

How can I convert a rectangle to triangle by using shortcuts in Adobe Illustrator?

Like this:

[image: like this]

Answer (score 7):

You could use the Direct Selection Tool to select, then delete the top path.

Select the top 2 anchors and <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to average and join them.

[image]

---

To address the specifics of the question... moving the top corners simultaneously...

First, realize that I, personally, would **not** create a *triangle* this way. It leaves 2 anchors at the top, which is not only inefficient, but can also present other construction issues.

However, if you *really* want to, you can use the **Free Transform Tool** and a perspective distortion, but not with shortcuts.

Draw the square/rectangle and select it. Choose the Free Transform Tool, click the `Perspective` option on the popup tool bar...

[image]

... drag a top corner.

[image]

Alternatively, with the Free Transform Tool, you can ...

1. Click a corner
2. Hold down <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
3. Drag inward

You **must do things in this *specific* order** for the modifier keys to work. - Click, keys, drag - Any other order and it won't work.

---

And of course if you merely need a triangle from scratch, use the **Polygonal Tool**. Drag to draw, and while *still dragging* tap the **Down Arrow** <kbd>↓</kbd> to reduce the number of sides down to 3. Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down to keep the bottom edge at a 90° angle (straight).

[image]

Comment: Great idea! Learn another shortcut~

Comment: Metis you are fantastic! Do you know a way to do what the poster asked in comment, to move one corner point and have it move the other equally?

Comment: @Webster edited answer, but as noted.. not a great way to make triangles.

Answer (score 3):

With the white arrow tool select only the top 2 corners of the square.

Use Align Center on the 2 points.

Merge the points or just use the triangle as it is.

[image]

Comment: I was watching a video created by a designer and he is doing an action like dragging something and both top points can move at the same time, so it can be a trapezoid when he was doing that... sorry it is my fault that not state my question clear, but your solution is still a great option for me!

Comment: Like your Avatar too!

Comment: @Yapyaap that would be scale tool

Answer (score 0):

Would probably be easier to just delete either the top-right or top-left point, then drag the remaining top point midway between the bottom ones.

Comment: I tried several ways to create one triangle, just I don't know that one and I want to know. Thanks for the answer though:)